# Why would a intelligent and manipulative demon in human body not integrate in society?

Tags: society, creature-design

I have a demon (Jhora, Rakshesha), which has a very attractive female human body who has to drink human blood to survive. It was banned from the city where the other demons live.

Jhora is very intelligent, seductive and very manipulative. She can control almost every human being and has the power to rule companies, countries, and everything.

In this world all creatures that are non-human and completely fictional in our world, such as vampires, golems, etc. don't live among people but on their own. Why?

Most of these creatures are strong and intelligent enough to protect themselves easily from human police or government, some of them could be on the top of society if they wanted. They could live a life with all of human pleasures (which my Rakshesha really likes). So why shouldn't they do that in this world?

Remember: She is highly intelligent, so no police would ever discover her demon form.

Comment: Ego. Humans don't live among cattle either.

Comment: @nzaman: Cattle ranchers do.

Comment: @jamesqf: Not by choice, but because they need to look after their stock

Comment: "site for writers, artists and others using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings."

Humans are powerless compared to these other beings. Why do they let humans have cities, countries, etc? Why are humans not pushed out into the scraps of worthless land that nobody wants, like indian reservations? 

It is a big cultural question and a world where it is not answered is way incomplete. Remove mention of the particular demon, and ask why a whole lot of demons would every single one leave humans alone.

Comment: This question is in the VTR queue, but I cannot vote to reopen it, even with the edit.  Our [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) clearly states that questions about "the actions of individual characters, rather than elements of the world they inhabit, character building, and elements of plot" are off-topic.  To make this question on-topic, 100% of the individual character must be removed from the question.  It must become, "why would people of Culture A not be willing to live among culture B" (\*continued\*)

Comment: With complete descriptions of cultures A and B and the social difficulties between them that keep them apart, and a list of qualifications for what would make the best answer.

Comment: @nzaman: OK, change cattle to deer.  Quite a few humans live in close proximity to deer (friends have some that often sleep under their deck during the day), and like the demon, may occasionally kill one for food.  Yet few of us try to integrate ourselves into a deer herd, or become the prime buck :-)  We manipulate them somewhat, but only to serve our purposes, not theirs.

Answer (score 8):

Just because nobody would discover she's a demon doesn't mean they wouldn't discover she's a threat. In the wider world, if she pushes for the top, she is inevitably going to be brought into competition with the best and brightest of her chosen field: the best rulers, the best cops, the best CEOs, the best criminal masterminds (who are trying to manipulate those same people). Can she beat them *all*? Does she want to put forth that much effort?

If she keeps to herself, nobody will bother her. And that needn't preclude a *little* fun here and there. (Who's going to miss one or two humans? There's so *many* of them!)

Also, you mention that there's a whole city of other demons who, presumably, don't think of her talents as all that special. (They *did* exile her, after all.) If she gets to be too prominent in her new position, some of them might come after her, for old grudges, because they feel it's their duty to help the humans, or simply to prevent her from becoming a threat in the future.

Answer (score 1):

She hasn't been socialized.

Just because you are intelligent doesn't mean you can instantly integrate into a completely new society. Social norms have to be taught and are often a long arduous process taking years of not decades. It's even worse for her because she is not human and does not even come equipped with the same basic instincts as humans, and does not have human parents to drill her in those norms. She might be able to pass by minimizing contact but prolonged contact with humans will expose her. It is a self fulfilling problem minimizing contact leads to less and less understanding of ever changing social norms.

Comment: Yeah that would work, but I think I can't make her that young. In my version she lives on earth since at least year 0

Comment: that doesn't mean she has been socialized. If anything being that old might make it worse, think about how out of touch even old humans can be with modern social norms and technology, now amplify that by the thousands without even the initial socialization to mitigate. The modern age may well be overwhelming, the average person receives more written information in a week than they did in their entire lives a few hundred years ago. She may have only just started to acknowledge the internet as more than a fad.

Answer (score 1):

**Humans are exhausting.**

Humans enjoy the excitement of nightclubs or paintball ranges.  It is exciting and stimulating and thrilling.  But even for humans enough is enough - it is good to leave when you have had your fill and go lie on the beanbag and eat Cheetohs and watch "How It's Made".

So too your demon.  She has a hot human body but she is ancient.  The humans are fun in small doses but the hubbub and bustle of these short-lived, excitable mortals is exhausting.  It frays her nerves (and those of her kind).  This is in large part because it is difficult for high-end monsters like her to shut them out - a wall and a door is enough for a human to feel alone but she can perceive all the intelligences around her in a wide radius.  Their emotions and fears are delectable but living full time with the humans is like drinking from a firehose.

She has to escape.  Alone is OK.  The crystalline, predictable mental rhythms of her kind are relaxing and would be better but she is probably better off without those assholes - certainly safer.

Answer (score 0):

My question would be, why wouldn't she integrate herself into society? She needs blood to survive and apparently possesses the skillset needed to gain a high status in society. The only reason I could think of is that she feels guilty about what she is and what she has to do in order to survive. Maybe denying herself fame and power is her way of punishing herself for having to drink human blood.

Of course, she is a demon, but maybe demons in this world happen to have morals, or maybe the soul of her human host has influenced her over time.

Comment: She has no morals, this character is for a RPG, and somehow the creatures shouldn't be integrated in human society. I don't want it that way, as I think it wouldn't be very intelligent to refuse Jhora the power she can have (and I have made a cool character for her).

Comment: Ah, so essentially there's a rule forbidding you from making this character integrate with society. In that case, maybe they simply dont want to have to deal with an overpowered character?

Comment: I don't know if it is a rule there. I haven't read that anywhere xD

Answer (score 0):

Cultural and traditional differences. This is quite prevalent in the world, where you will often times find small communities of one ethnic group or similar. As far as just taking over humans, what's the population difference? Are there so many humans the others races wouldn't dare to go to war? Maybe because Rakshesha  *likes* the human socially life is the reason she got banned?